# SpringBoot raise SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'shopstat' in @PostConstruct code block

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource

I got a SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'xxxx', during running of my springboot application.

My code is like this:

```
@Slf4j
public abstract class Observer{
    @Resource
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void recover() throws SQLException {
       log.info("he-----y {} {}", dataSource.getMaxIdle(),dataSource.getConnection());
    }

    public void handle() throws SQLException {
       log.info("he-----y {} {}", dataSource.getMaxIdle(),dataSource.getConnection());
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class DimPageDetailObserver extends Observer {
}
```

As you can see, I wanna print datasource info in `@PostConstruct` code block, but I encountered following exception.

However when I remove the `log.info("he-----y {} {}", dataSource.getMaxIdle(),dataSource.getConnection());` from `@PostConstruct` code block, and use a controller to trigger the `handle()` method, it runs very well.

```
2020-07-08 17:38:30,228| ERROR| main| o.springframework.boot.SpringApplication| 815| Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dimPageJobApiImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dimPageObserver': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'shopstat'
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
        at com.xiaomi.youpin.data.schedule.jobs.server.Main.main(Main.java:30)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dimPageObserver': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'shopstat'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:627)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318)
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'shopstat'
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
        at com.xiaomi.youpin.data.schedule.jobs.server.service.component.Observer.recover(Observer.java:72)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
        ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Here's the application.yml:

```
    spring:
      datasource:
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        url: jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxxxxxxx:3306/shopstat?allowMultiQueries=true&charset=utf8mb4&serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=utf-8
        username: xxx
        password: xxx
        hikari:
          maximum-pool-size: 10
          minimum-idle: 5
```

I changed my code into another version to check whether the Bean of datasource caused problem. But I think it's not.

Observer.java

```
@Slf4j
public abstract class Observer{
    @Resource
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void recover() throws SQLException {
       log.info("he-----y {} {}", dataSource.getMaxIdle(),dataSource.getConnection());
    }

    public void handle() throws SQLException {
       log.info("he-----y {} {}", dataSource.getMaxIdle(),dataSource.getConnection());
    }
}
```

DimPageDetailObserver.java

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class DimPageDetailObserver extends Observer {
}
```

Main.java

```
@ComponentScan(...)
@MapperScan(...)
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OjServerApplication.class, args);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @SneakyThrows
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
                // Here I call the recover
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

I think after 30 seconds sleeping, everything is done, but it still threw the same exception.

Comment: Why? Also you have a connection leak here as you aren't closing the connection afterwards!. And apparently you are connecting to a db that isn't available (yet). Generally DB access from a postconstruct is a bad idea (as not everything is up and running just yet).

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm not going to print my datasource info, the code shown above have already simplified so that you can understand the problem easily.

By the way, I tryed to run the same code after everything is ok(I sleep 30seconds after spingboot's running) but it still threw the same exception.

Comment: Where did you put the sleep? INside the post construct? That halts the whole proces. Don't place a dumbed down version here, post actual code (wouldn't be the first nor the last one who dumbed down and lost important information that way). As stated with this cod eyou have a connection leak.

Comment: No, I started a new thread after SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);, where I put my sleep and trigger the recover() method. sry I can't show you all the code.

Comment: Try to use @ Autowired instead of @ Resource to inject the Datasource.

Comment: Putting the sleep after the run doesn't add anything. The application is up-and-running already and the `@PostConstruct` method has already been called. If the run method is done, the application is up.

Comment: @M.Deinum In the sleep version of my code, I remove the ```@PostConstruct```. I call the recover method after the application is up. I updated the sleep version above.

I cannot figure out where's the problem since I think the application is already up in this case.

Comment: I changed my code since I can't fix it. At least I know never call datasource related method this way. Thanks to you guys.